# 16:9 video displayed in 4:3 frame at blogger

Tags: video, blogger, aspect-ratio

Whenever I upload a 16:9 video into a post on blogger.com, the video is displayed in a 4:3 frame, with black bars on the top and bottom. How can I display the video in a 16:9 frame?

I know I can upload a video to YouTube and then get embed code from YouTube to put into the HTML code of my post at blogger, but I'd like to avoid those extra steps if possible. I presume there is some HTML code at blogger that is forcing the 4:3 frame. If I could modify that code I might be able to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you go into HTML view and share the code for the video inserted in the post? That might help us help you better...

Comment: Here's a page that has two 16:9 videos displayed in 4:3 frames:
https://johnlinkbikingadventures.blogspot.com/2019/08/riding-day-67-august-21st-2019.html?fbclid=IwAR0eqxs2p5uI1pcRg7FKdZ2OateHCYjlqhvot8rJE2Gr77QKSFJot-gKeSo

Comment: Here's the HTML code automatically created by the insertion of the first video:

<object class="BLOG_video_class" contentid="9ec82a199b4564b2" height="399" id="BLOG_video-9ec82a199b4564b2" width="480"></object>

Comment: Here's the HTML code automatically created by the insertion of the second video:

<object class="BLOG_video_class" contentid="451878277fdfdc3e" height="399" id="BLOG_video-451878277fdfdc3e" width="480"></object>

Comment: try to play with the values in Width and Height.... Maybe width="650" height="366"...

Comment: Setting the values of height and width as you suggest results in vertical as well as horizontal bars.

Comment: I found the code in my next two comments in the HTML for the template I used to create my blog. I think that 4:3 might be the culprit. I hesitate to change it to 16:9 in my bog so I created another blog with the same template in order to test the change to 16:9, but the code below does not appear in the template for the new blog.

Comment: <b:defaultmarkups>
      <b:defaultmarkup type='Common'>
        <b:includable id='responsiveImage' var='settings'>
          <b:comment>Add in the high-res thumb for youtube images.</b:comment>
          <b:if cond='not data:settings.image.isYoutube'>
            <b:include data='settings' name='super.responsiveImage'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:with value='resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage.youtubeMaxResDefaultUrl, 1152, &quot;4:3&quot;)' var='highRes'>

Comment: The code above is followed by this code:

<b:include data='{                                  image: data:settings.image,                                  imageSizes: [320,490],                                  sourceSizes: &quot;(max-width: 640px) 100vw, (max-width: 1024px) 576px, 490px&quot;,                                  enhancedSourceset: data:highRes                                }' name='super.responsiveImage'/>
            </b:with>
          </b:if>
        </b:includable>
      </b:defaultmarkup>

Comment: Setting the width and height to an aspect ratio of 16:9 *does* result in a 16:9 video being displayed in a 16:9 frame. But the preview image has bars on the top and bottom. That's why I said above "Setting the values of height and width as you suggest results in vertical as well as horizontal bars." I saw the bars on the preview and didn't play the video.